# How to get delete word combination "Name Server:" without quotes but keep 'Name Server:someletters/digits' in sed

Tags: bash, shell, sed

I have the following lines:

Name Server:NS92.WORLDNIC.COM(or some other value)
Name Server:
Name Server:
Name Server:

Please see the screenshot for better understanding: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Ng3K.jpg
How do I get rid of the 'Name Server:' line but keep the line with the value?

I tried /Name Server:{0,0}/d but it deletes all lines.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get the following two lines to work:

I believe the [:space:] is POSIX compliant:

```
cat test |sed '/^Name Server:[[:space:] \t]\?$/d'
```

An alternative is simply:

```
cat test |sed '/^Name Server:[ \t]\?$/d'
```

I've also found in sed, that most of the meta-characters (eg + ? ) need to be escaped for sed to recognize them correctly.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Could you please explain why is there a space following :? I've checked via notepad++ only \n follows the ':' Also I have troubles understanding why $ is there. Should be noted it worked without the tab  character.

Comment: You can avoid 'cat'. Just use: sed '/^Name Server:[ \t]\?$/d' < test

Comment: Hey Simon, the space with the ? is a safety - for zero or more of the previous characters (a space or tab). Not sure why it might not be showing a space in notepad++ (a setting somewhere?). The $ is there to match the complete line ... and ensure there are only spaces (or nothing) until the end of the line.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
echo "Name Server:NS92.WORLDNIC.COM" | sed 's/^Name Server://'
```

Comment: Thanks but I needed to keep this line and remove the others

Answer (score 0):

```
cut -d ":" -f 2 < ff | sed '/^$/d'
```

Uses ':' as delimiter and splits the line (-d option), then selects the second field (-f option)

Comment: Thanks, but I need those lines gone, with this command they remain empty

Comment: Oh.. Ididn't know that was required. Edited my answer just to show how to do that. But i don't prefer this (using 2 programs). Rather go for the soloutions others have given.